# CleverCSS complaining when using gradient functions, is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: python, css, clevercss

I'm trying to use -webkit-linear-gradient inside of CleverCSS.  However, when I try to "compile" it, I get an error of `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Here is the CleverCSS

```
button:
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6)
```

If I throw that into `clevercss.convert()`, that's the error I get. I see that parenthesis have special meaning in CleverCSS, but I'm unsure if this is a result of that or not.  Is there a way to have CleverCSS process this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the backtick operator for verbatim CSS:

```
background-image: `-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6)`
```

The “official” PyPI version of CleverCSS [isn't maintained](https://github.com/clevercss/clevercss/pull/13#issuecomment-2474268) and may not have that feature; get an updated version [from Github](https://github.com/clevercss/clevercss).

Comment: That's it! I was using PyPi version as well. The github version worked.